# Compare element of int array to an int

Tags: java

Hi I'm seeking to understand in java how you can take an int array and then in an if statement compare one single element from the int array against just a declared int. I want to just simply compare two ints against each other but one is inside of an int array. The == I guess doesn't work?

```
for (int count = 5; count >= 0; count--) {
                if (gameBoardTokens[count] == 0) {
                    if (playerOneTurn) {
                        gameBoardTokens[count] = 1;
                        count = 0;
                    } else {
                        gameBoardTokens[count] = 2;
                        count = 0;
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you think this `gameBoardTokens[count] == 0` does?

Comment: The code inside the for-loop is not executed because `count` is never smaller than -1

Comment: From the research I have done I understand that == just compares references and not the actual int value contained in the array.

Comment: FYI: Please do not edit your question in any way that invalidates existing comments or answers.  It makes the question and the answers useless and distracting to other people who may be having a similar problem.  Instead of changing your previous example, it would have been better to add an "updated example" to the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this (count < -1) for this (count > -1)
because  at first 5 > -1 not -1 > 5.

Comment: Please consider to remove your answer because the question initiator did change her/his code based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`gameBoardTokens[count] == 0` works. The thing that makes your code unfunctional is that the code in the `for`-loop is never executed, because `count` is initially 5, for which `count < -1` is `false`. So the loop immediately aborts.